# Generating a zoo of animals

Tags: c++, c++11, template, inheritance

The pattern I've come up here is for the `AnimalGenerator` itself, outside of the (abstract) Factory Pattern used within it.  The factory classes themselves are not present in this code because that is not what I'm focussing on here.

There are many types of animals, and `AnimalGenerator::generateAnimals<Type>(num, int...)` is to generate `num` specific types of animals (randomly chosen) that are of category `Type` with the `int...` pack specifying how many there are of each specific type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

class Animal { public: virtual std::string tag() const = 0; };
class Dog : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Dog";} };
class Cat : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Cat";} };
class Trout : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Trout";} };
class Whale : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Whale";} };
class Wolf : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Wolf";} };
class Deer : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Deer";} };
class Fox : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Fox";} };
class Shark : public Animal { virtual std::string tag() const override {return "Shark";} };

enum {Land, Water};

class AnimalGenerator {
    public:
        template <int, typename... Args> static inline std::list<Animal*> generateAnimals (int, Args...);
    private:
        template <int, int> struct CreateNewAnimals;
        template <int> struct Animals;
        template <int> static inline std::list<Animal*> createNewAnimals (int, int);
};

template <>
struct AnimalGenerator::Animals<Land> {
    using type = std::tuple<Dog, Cat, Wolf, Deer, Fox>;
    static const int size = std::tuple_size<type>::value;
};

template <>
struct AnimalGenerator::Animals<Water> {
    using type = std::tuple<Trout, Whale, Shark>;
    static const int size = std::tuple_size<type>::value;
};

template <int AnimalType, typename... Args>
inline std::list<Animal*> AnimalGenerator::generateAnimals (int numTypes, Args... numAppearing) {
    std::deque<int> sequence (Animals<AnimalType>::size);
    std::iota (sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0);
    std::random_shuffle (sequence.begin(), sequence.end());
    sequence.resize(numTypes);
    std::list<Animal*> animals;
    std::list<int> numberAppearing = {numAppearing...};
    while (!sequence.empty()) {
        const std::list<Animal*> newAnimals = createNewAnimals<AnimalType> (sequence.front(), numberAppearing.front());
        std::copy (newAnimals.begin(), newAnimals.end(), std::back_inserter(animals));
        sequence.pop_front();  numberAppearing.pop_front();
    }
    return animals;
}

template <int N, int AnimalType>
struct AnimalGenerator::CreateNewAnimals : CreateNewAnimals<N-1, AnimalType> {
    std::list<Animal*> operator()(int n, int numAppearing) {
        if (N == n) {
            std::list<Animal*> animals;
            for (int i = 0; i < numAppearing; i++)
            animals.emplace_back (new typename std::tuple_element<N, typename Animals<AnimalType>::type>::type);
// Each of the Animal subtypes will have their own Factory class to create the specific animal with all of its unique traits.
// But I omit this Abstract Factory pattern here for simplicity and simply create one using 'new' instead.
            return animals;
        }
        return CreateNewAnimals<N-1, AnimalType>::operator()(n, numAppearing);
    }
};

template <int AnimalType>
struct AnimalGenerator::CreateNewAnimals<-1, AnimalType> {
    std::list<Animal*> operator()(int, int) {return std::list<Animal*>();}  // End of recursion.
};

template <int AnimalType>
inline std::list<Animal*> AnimalGenerator::createNewAnimals (int type, int numAppearing) {
    return CreateNewAnimals<Animals<AnimalType>::size - 1, AnimalType>()(type, numAppearing);
}

int main() {
    const int seed = std::time(nullptr);
    std::srand(seed);

    const std::list<Animal*> landAnimals = AnimalGenerator::generateAnimals<Land>(3, 4,2,5);
    // 3 land animals types created, 4 of the first type, 2 of the second type, 5 of the third type.
    for (const Animal* x : landAnimals)
        std::cout << x->tag() << std::endl;

    const std::list<Animal*> waterAnimals = AnimalGenerator::generateAnimals<Water>(2, 6,1);
    for (const Animal* x : waterAnimals)
        std::cout << x->tag() << std::endl;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```
> Cat
> Cat
> Cat
> Cat
> Wolf
> Wolf
> Deer
> Deer
> Deer
> Deer
> Deer
> Shark
> Shark
> Shark
> Shark
> Shark
> Shark
> Whale
> ```

I welcome criticisms of this design so that I may seek improvements.

Answer (score 2):

- Those child classes may be somewhat short, but they would still look more readable as multiple lines.  Also, if they ever need to be maintained, it would be harder to do so with them as single lines.  Rule of thumb: code is primarily meant to be read vertically.
- The `enum` looks a little unusual as it's lacking a name that describe the types:

  > ```
  > enum {Land, Water};
  > ```

  Try something like this:

  ```
  enum Environment { Land, Water };
  ```
- Since you appear to be using C++11, you should consider some C++11 alternatives, such as [`std::shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead of `std::random_shuffle()`.  The former requires an RNG as an argument, so you're not stuck using the deprecated and [unsafe](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) `std::rand()`.  You should also use this in place of `std::srand()`.
- Regarding `std::srand()` anyway, `seed` is wrong since `std::time()` doesn't return an `int`, but an `std::time_t`.  You should especially be careful about types when it comes to time.
- You probably don't need to use `std::endl` at all in `main()`.  It also flushes the buffer, so it's generally slower, especially when used repeatedly.  Newlines can also be outputted using `"\n"`, which doesn't do any flushing.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) for more information.